Nginx File Type Change New URL
# NGINX will create a cache capable of storing 100MB of keys and 1000MB of data.
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cdn2 levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx_cdn2:100M max_size=1G inactive=40d;
#log_subrequest on;
# front facing virtual host for caching


# resizing server
server {
    listen 10177;
    server_name image_resize_server;
    
    location ~ ^/img/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+) {
        error_page 415 =404 /empty.gif;
        image_filter_buffer 20M;
        image_filter_jpeg_quality $3; # Desired JPG quality
        image_filter_interlace on; # For progressive JPG
        image_filter resize $1 $2;
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/img/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*) $4 break;
        return 400;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10178/img/$uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+) {
        error_page 415 =404 /empty.gif;
        image_filter_buffer 20M;
        image_filter_jpeg_quality $2; # Desired JPG quality
        image_filter_interlace on; # For progressive JPG
        image_filter resize $1 -;
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*) $3 break;
        return 400;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10178/img/$uri;
    }  
  
}
# back-end virtual host for retrieving file from AWS
server {
    listen 10178;
    server_name second_proxy_server;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;  # Use Google for DNS.
    resolver_timeout 60s;
    #set $backend  cdn.xxx.com/buyuk ;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;  # Not needed by AWS.
    proxy_pass_request_headers off;
    # Clean up the headers going to and from S3.
    proxy_hide_header "x-amz-id-2";
    proxy_hide_header "x-amz-request-id";
    proxy_hide_header "x-amz-storage-class";
    proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_connect_timeout   60;
    proxy_send_timeout      60;
    proxy_read_timeout      60;
    
location ~ ^/img/(.+) {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/img/(.*) $1 break;
        return 400;
  
        proxy_pass https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.xxx.com/buyuk/$uri;
        error_page 415 =404 /empty.gif;
        proxy_cache nginx_cdn2;
        proxy_cache_key "temp_$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
        # proxy_cache_lock on; # Allow only one request
        proxy_cache_valid 60s;
        expires 60s;
    }
}

http://111.111.111.11:10177/img/800/85/pastel-silky-dream-fondoten-de6a.webp
I want to direct incoming requests here
http://111.111.111.11:10177/img/800/85/pastel-silky-dream-fondoten-de6a.jpg
I converted all the images on my server to jpg format. But there are requests coming via webp. I want to convert these to jpg too.
